Configure Backup Password Directory option is missing from LAPS under Administrative Templates in Group Policy Manager
I'm trying to configure LAPS in an Active Directory environment (Windows Server 2022), but an important setting (Configure Backup Password Directory) is missing from the LAPS section under Administrative templates.
The current options are visible:
Password Settings;
Name of administrator account to manage;
Do not allow password expiration time longer than required;
Enable local admin password management
But several settings are missing.  These are:
Enable password backup for DSWM accounts
Configure size of encrypted password history
Enable password encryption
Configure authorized password decryptors
Most important, I'm missing Configure password backup directory, without which LAPS will not work properly.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can add the missing options to LAPS in Group Policy Management Console?
Thank you very much for any tips and suggestions.
I tried the following powershell commands:
Get-Command -Module LAPS
Update-LAPSADSchema and
Update-LapsADSchema –verbose
But the other settings/options are still missing from Group Policy Manager.
Interestingly, when I look at the ADMX and ADML files in Notepad, I can see those settings.  So if they are in the files, why are the settings not visible in Group Policy Editor?
An additional note: The Group Policy Editor shows that "Policy definitions (ADMX files) retrieved from the local computer".  And the ADMX and ADML files are in what I believe to be the correct folders.  LAPS.ADMX is in c:\Windows\Policy Definitions and the LAPS.ADML file is in c:\Windows\Policy Definitions\en-us
